# Start/stop jquery when other function is running

Tags: jquery, function

I have a page help tooltip running on the page that displays on hover. Running under a separate function I am using the same tooltip tool to run a tutorial which goes through steps(a series of 12 tooltips each activated by the previous/next button) If you are in the middle of the tutorial and hover over one of the items that is not included in the tutorial it kills the tutorial and then you have to start over. When the jquery is ran for the tutorial I want to disable the page help tooltip and re-enable it when the tutorial has been exited.

I tried adding a few different things that did not work...

```
window.addBlockMouseEvent = function () { return false; };
```

and also...

```
function stopAddBlockMouseEvent() {
return false;
};
```

neither had the desired result. Still really new at this, any help is appreciated, This question was closed before, I am not sure how to explain what it is I need more clearly.

solution found:
Or if for some reason we want to hide only a sub-set of the tooltips, we can define a parent common to them

```
$('.selector').qtip({
content: {
    text: 'I hide other tooltips when I'm shown... booya!'
},
show: {
    solo: $('.qtips') // Hide tooltips within the .qtips      element when shown
}
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain how you implement tooltips? Are you using jQueryUI?

Comment: What are `stopAddBlockMouseEvent` and `window.addBlockMouseEvent` supposed to be? the named function that you passed as a callback to the mystery tooltip plugin?

Comment: Stefano: I used the qtip jqueryui http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/.

Comment: Kevin: I am not exactly sure as I said I am very new to jquery and have been thrown into the deep end at my job so I am trying to figure it out. I search for various options to "kill" a function and those were 2 of the several options that I found and tried

Comment: JAAulde: I apologize for my lack of know-how and the correct use for tools. I looked at a couple jQuery UI Modals and could not get them to do exactly what I needed. Any helpful suggestion you may have would be appreciated. I need a modal that will behave as a tool tip as well. pointing to and explaining multiple items on the page. Thx

Comment: Another question then... What brought you to making those two attempts? on their one they don't mean anything to us because we cant' see the rest of your code/page.

Comment: Just an update... for certain situations the qtip is the perfect tool for a tutorial (as it was in my case) see link below
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/advanced/#stepbystep

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two ways

1. Use different class names,  which specifically work for your help tooltip and for the tutorial tooltip. And then remove the class for the help tooltip when you want to run tutorial tooltip.

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

1. I would suggest you to look into jQuery UI Modals. They would eventually hide the background  of the page so that your tutorial works independently of the page tooltip.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

I Hope I understood your question properly.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions I believe the first one you offered if very simple to the resolution that I found.
https://github.com/Craga89/qTip2/wiki/Show (see edit to original question)